# Add a permanent scrollbar to a full screen pdf without changing any settings in the reader or removing the touch mode feature

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, interactive

A little bit of a niche question.

I have created an interactive pdf that opens in full screen mode (which is a mandatory) and in single pages which works well and includes the touch scroll.

One thing that has been requested (and I understand from some users perspective as it's a more traditional approach to page scrolling) is to force/ enable the scroll bars which currently do not exist. This would need to be enabled within the distributed pdf file rather than within the reader's settings.

I am guessing that this may require a snippet of code if it is at all possible.

Comment: There's not anything you can do to force full-screen. You have no say over what app a PDF is opened in, nor even what platform. You don't know if your user even has a touch-screen... & scroll-bars are applied by the OS. I can switch mine on & off from a system control panel.

Comment: That should be an answer @Tetsujin `:)`

Comment: @Scott - I would, but I'm not sure how to turn a grumpy comment into an 'accurate answer, with citations' ;-)

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Just to provide this as an actual answer, though it comes without citation...</sup>

These are things over which you have no control.

There's nothing you can do to force full-screen.
You have no say over what app a PDF is opened in, nor even what platform.
You don't know if your user even has a touch-screen... & scroll-bars are applied by the OS.
I can switch mine on & off from a system control panel.

Essentially, all these elements are controlled by your client, not you as a content supplier.

Any reputable OS/App combo would stop you in your tracks if you tried to force settings on a user.
You do not have admin rights on their device.

PDF stands for "Portable Document Format". Essentially it is [or ought to be but isn't quite] a WYSIWYG graphics format. Additional functionality can be used if [& only if] your end user is using Adobe's own PDF Viewer. If they aren't, you have considerably less control.